# User without licence to access community website?

Tags: visualforce, community, salesforce-id

My org is planning for a low budget app. So can we have only one salesforce user and setup a rest api. Then all the user we need to access is added to contacts. Then can we use those users to login and others on community through rest api query?

Comment: For communities there are separate licences which are used to create users linked to the contact records, these are cheaper than full SF licences and can login to the community to use some Salesforce functionality (what they can see or do varies by licence type).

Comment: Are you asking if you can use a rest API and use a single user account for all of the community users. If so that is not how SF communities is designed to work. Please clarify that in your question and see [ask] for guidance on how to ask a question.

Comment: @DaveHumm  _Are you asking if you can use a rest API and use a single user account for all of the community users_ This is what am asking here. Can I get some valid reasons why we cnt achieve this. Since we have 15000 api hits per day for an org .Also do you think concurrency hit affect this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **cannot** have only one Community User setup and allow other "Contacts" to be able to login to the Community using REST API.

Every Community User is associated to a Contact record and in turn an Account and have their own credentials whenever they are setup as Users (see more on [Create Communities Users](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_create_external_users.htm&type=5)). While accessing any REST API, you first authenticate the User and then get access to the resources. So if you setup only One User, and use only that User to authenticate the API, every time you are necessarily logging in as the same User and getting access to the resources which the User is authorized to, and not ***as*** any other User.

If you are looking to expose data which is not too sensitive without investing much into licenses, then you should look into [Guest Profiles](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rss_config_guest_user_profile.htm) and enabling [Public access to your Community](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_public_access.htm&type=5).